# Help finding the arc length of a polar curve?

Tags: calculus

Find the arc length of the polar curve $r = 8\sin^3\left(\frac{\theta}3\right)$ from $0\leq\theta\leq \frac{\pi}4$.

I found $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=8\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}3\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}3\right)$ and plugged it into the formula:

$$
\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\sqrt{64\sin^6\left(\frac{\theta }{\:3}\right)+8\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta }{3}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta }{3}\right)}\:d\theta
$$

(Sorry I'm not sure how to insert this, [here is a link](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cint&space;_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi&space;%7D%7B4%7D%7D%5Csqrt%7B64sin%5E6%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Ctheta&space;%7D%7B%5C:3%7D%5Cright)+8sin%5E2%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Ctheta&space;%7D%7B3%7D%5Cright)cos%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Ctheta&space;%7D%7B3%7D%5Cright)%7D%5C:d%5Ctheta))

How would I go about simplifying this integral?

Comment: You should have $$s = \int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}\right)^2} \mathrm d\theta$$, you have seemingly missed the square unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, it looks like you've used,

$$s = \int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}\right)} \mathrm d\theta$$

Instead of

$$s = \int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}\right)^2} \mathrm d\theta$$

Hence you should have,

$$s = \int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{64\sin^6\left(\frac \theta 3\right) + 64\sin^4\left(\frac \theta 3\right)\cos^2\left(\frac \theta 3\right)} \mathrm d\theta$$

Using the Pythagorean identity,
$$s = \int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{64\sin^6\left(\frac \theta 3\right) + 64\sin^4\left(\frac \theta 3\right)\left(1-\sin^2\left(\frac \theta 3\right)\right)}\mathrm d\theta$$

Expanding,
$$s = \int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{64\sin^6\left(\frac \theta 3\right) + 64\sin^4\left(\frac \theta 3\right) - 64\sin^6\left(\frac \theta 3\right)}\mathrm d\theta$$

Hence, 
$$s = 8\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \sqrt{\sin^4\left(\frac \theta 3\right)}\mathrm d\theta$$

Which can be evaluated rather straightforwardly.

Comment: Your $r^2$ should be $1$

Comment: no, it's correct as-is, note that we're working in polar coords